# Why is HttpContext.User null after AuthenticateRequest is complete

Tags: asp.net, authentication, httpcontext

The standard way to check if the current request is authenticated is with `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.  I have just run into a case where the `User` property is null so I cannot make the check!

I found [an article describing the IIS request pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis).  I'm at the `PostResolveRequestCache` stage which is clearly *after* `AuthenticateRequest`!  Why would `HttpContext.User` still be null at that point?

Answer (score 1):

The `FormsAuthenticationModule` was not running.  I had to manually add it to my `web.config` and `User` was no longer null.  I [am investigating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23613190/794234) what caused the module not to run here.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on at what point of the request lifecycle you are checking this value. In your case, prefix your check for IsAuthenticated with a check for HttpContext.User == null. If NULL, not authenticated. :)

Comment: Can you provide a reference source for null meaning not authenticated?

Comment: If `User` is null, then it would stand to reason that they're not authenticated, wouldn't it?  The bigger question would be why is `User` null in the `HttpContext`.

Comment: I believe this _also_ happens when the Session times-out.

Comment: Well, read both my statements separately. [1] Null would depend on stage of request lifecycle, [2] for the test if the user is authenticated, maybe you could use User=Null as a good enough check as well before checking all those sub properties.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that HttpContext.User is null that no user authenticated jet.
You may use Request.IsAuthenticated instead to check, and move to HttpContext.User only if it's true!